# odtphp encoding error with PHP 5.4

Tags: php

One of my clients is using the library odtphp, since the upgrade from PHP 5.2.8 to PHP 5.4.14 there is one issue with segments containing extended characters (example : é à ô, etc).

There is no information about compatibility on their [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/odtphp/wiki/Home/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching directly inside the library, I've been able to find how to fix encoding problems by replacing these lines :

**odf.php:85**

```
$value = $encode ? htmlspecialchars($value) : $value;
```

with

```
$value = $encode ? htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401,"ISO-8859-1") : $value;
```

**odf.php:214**

```
if (preg_match($reg, html_entity_decode($this->contentXml), $m) == 0) {
```

with

```
if (preg_match($reg, html_entity_decode($this->contentXml,ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401,"ISO-8859-1"), $m) == 0) {
```

**Segment.php:141**

```
$value = $encode ? htmlspecialchars($value) : $value;
```

with

```
$value = $encode ? htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401,"ISO-8859-1") : $value;
```

Hope this will help someone!

Comment: The default encoding parameter has changed for those functions. Fix looks good. Don't forget to report upstream.